# SQl query for overlap of users in different stream service?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to sql and keen to learn but i'm having trouble with this problem. I would appreciate any help. I have a login table with following column and i have explained the columns below.

```
    id  cur_date    user_id stream  user_signup tot_sec mov_sec ser_sec
    1   19-MAY-20   5right  TV      12-MAY-20   73430   73430   0
    2   19-MAY-20   5right  TV      12-JAN-16   3430    3430    0
    3   19-MAY-20   5left   MOBILE  03-JAN-20   3457    3430    45
    4   19-MAY-20   7left   MOBILE  04-JAN-20   4980    100     4880
    5   19-MAY-20   7right  Tv      04-FEB-20   15731   0       15731
    6   19-MAY-20   7right  WEB     04-APR-20   16731   1000    15731
    7   19-MAY-20   7left   TV      04-MAR-20   2731    1000    1731
    8   19-MAY-20   5left   TV      03-APR-20   12731   11000   1731


cur_date is when we take the user metrics
user_id (have same id on different stream service)
user_signup (user sign up date)
stream( streaming ways, contains 3 values mobile, web, TV)
tot_sec (total active time seconds)
mov_sec (watching movie time in seconds)
ser_sec(watching tv series time in seconds)
```

Quesion: write the SQL to which two stream have the greatest overlap of users? The users have the same id across stream service?

I wrote this:

```
 select r1.user_id, r1.stream  
from login as r1 
inner join login as r2  
on r1.user_id = r2.user_id 
order by r1.stream;
```

However this is not quite what im asking for. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If you mean the counts of logged in users, then you need some sort of aggregation to count.  So:

```
select s1.stream, s2.stream, count(*)
from login s1 join
     login s2
     on s1.user_id = s2.user_id and s1.stream <> s2.stream
group by s1.stream, s2.stream
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If the users can be repeated for a given stream, then you want `count(distinct s1.user_id)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: qq, When you say "users can be repeated for a given stream"? You mean they can login multiple times with different time stamps?

Comment: got it. This is just for user "sign up". But I appreciate the extra explanation. It helps me clarify the problem a lot. Thank you so much!!